# Laravel merge with $request

Tags: laravel, merge, controller

I'm trying to merge current user id with with a laravel $request and aftr merging all data will be saved into DB. After execution data save into DB but id save as a null value. Please see my code

```
public function store(Request $request, ClassModel $model)
{
    $model->create($request->merge(['created_user_id' => Auth::user()->id])->all());

    return redirect()->route('class.index')->withStatus(__('Class successfully created.'));
}
```

[image]
Can anyone tell me why user id dont save in DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your field is probably `nullable` but then in your `$fillable` array of the model (which is used for mass assignment protection), you forgot to include the `created_user_id` column. Please check that.